# Converting huge sets of data (dictionary) to tables

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, multiple-columns, rows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbFt0.png)I want to convert the data to a tabular format. Can you please help me with this. I have shown below the two rows of the extracted data from json files. I need to convert these in the tabular form. There are many such rows (over 5000); 2 of these rows are shown below.

```
{'HFProbeCounter': 1461593, 'Channel': 1, 'SeekOffset': 16, 'SelectedTool': 21, 'ActiveTool': 21, 'GCode': 'MSG("PLANEN , Tool : 001691_A")', 'IpoGC': 'G1', 'ipoReadError': None, 'laBuf': 1}

{'HFProbeCounter': 1461597, 'Channel': 1, 'SeekOffset': 20, 'SelectedTool': 21, 'ActiveTool': 21, 'GCode': 'N32 SUPA G0 Z=_Z_HOME D0', 'IpoGC': 'G0', 'ipoReadError': None, 'laBuf': 0}
```

I would like to get them into columns with the labels...

```
columns=['HFProbeCounter', 'Channel', 'SeekOffset', 'SelectedTool', 'ActiveTool', 'GCode', 'IpoGC', 'ipoReadError', 'laBuf']
```

I have tried using the following code, but since, the data set is huge, this code does not work:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

headers = ['HFProbeCounter', 'Channel', 'SeekOffset', 'SelectedTool', 'ActiveTool', 'GCode', 'IpoGC', 'ipoReadError', 'laBuf']
print(tabulate(data, headers=headers))
```

Comment: You can use [.read_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html#pandas-read-json) from pandas library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
data = [{'HFProbeCounter': 1461593, 'Channel': 1, 'SeekOffset': 16, 'SelectedTool': 21, 'ActiveTool': 21, 'GCode': 'MSG("PLANEN , Tool : 001691_A")', 'IpoGC': 'G1', 'ipoReadError': None, 'laBuf': 1},
        {'HFProbeCounter': 1461597, 'Channel': 1, 'SeekOffset': 20, 'SelectedTool': 21, 'ActiveTool': 21, 'GCode': 'N32 SUPA G0 Z=_Z_HOME D0', 'IpoGC': 'G0', 'ipoReadError': None, 'laBuf': 0}]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df

 HFProbeCounter  Channel  SeekOffset  ...  IpoGC  ipoReadError laBuf
0         1461593        1          16  ...     G1          None     1
1         1461597        1          20  ...     G0          None     0
```

Columns of this structure would be:

```
df.columns

Index(['HFProbeCounter', 'Channel', 'SeekOffset', 'SelectedTool', 'ActiveTool',
       'GCode', 'IpoGC', 'ipoReadError', 'laBuf'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: A valuable suggestion indeed. But, how do I assign the huge amount of data to the variable "data". Because, as you can see, I have attached an image which shows the code that I used to extract the data and then I have to convert this into a tabular form. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [pandas.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) method. As they exemplify:

```
>>> data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
   col_1 col_2
0      3     a
1      2     b
2      1     c
3      0     d
```

Like this you can directly convert this dictionary to a pandas DataFrame object which is what I can approximate more by what you meant by tabular format. Also pandas got a concatenation option that allow you to loop over multiple dictionaries leading then to a single dataframe:

```
my_table = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) for data in bunch_of_dictionaries])
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would deal with your issue, however I would first turn all these dicts into a list that contains them all. After that, you can simply use `pd.DataFrame()` and pass your list:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'HFProbeCounter': 1461593, 'Channel': 1, 'SeekOffset': 16, 'SelectedTool': 21, 'ActiveTool': 21, 'GCode': 'MSG("PLANEN , Tool : 001691_A")', 'IpoGC': 'G1', 'ipoReadError': None, 'laBuf': 1}
data_1 = {'HFProbeCounter': 1461597, 'Channel': 1, 'SeekOffset': 20, 'SelectedTool': 21, 'ActiveTool': 21, 'GCode': 'N32 SUPA G0 Z=_Z_HOME D0', 'IpoGC': 'G0', 'ipoReadError': None, 'laBuf': 0}

data_to_df = [data,data_1]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_to_df)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   HFProbeCounter  Channel  SeekOffset  SelectedTool  ActiveTool                            GCode IpoGC ipoReadError  laBuf
0         1461593        1          16            21          21  MSG("PLANEN , Tool : 001691_A")    G1         None      1
1         1461597        1          20            21          21         N32 SUPA G0 Z=_Z_HOME D0    G0         None      0
```